# Can't install PyQt 5 on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to install `PyQt5` on OS X with no success.
When I run `python3 configure.py` within the downloaded PyQt folder I receive the following:

```
Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.
```

My installed python version is 3.4.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using such sommand (you need to have a valid installation of qt5):

```
(sudo) python configure.py --qmake /path/to/your/qt/directory/with/qmake
```